# Multiple Templates TreeView with Caliburn Micro wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, caliburn.micro

I have a problem with my treeview. I am trying to use three layer structure of it but somehow when i put the hiearhical templates together the root node even though it contains children it does not show the expand button or allows me to expand it.

I have made my template around this article [TreeView Multiple Templates](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/treeview-data-binding-multiple-templates/)

So my xaml looks like this:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="150"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Operations}" Name="Operations">
                    <TreeView.Resources>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Operation}" ItemsSource="{Binding Operation}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                <TextBlock Text=" " ></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Parameters.Count}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Parameters}" ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=par}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Path}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=val}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Path}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Joints}" ItemsSource="{Binding Joints}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Par}" />
                                <TextBlock Text=" " ></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Val}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.Resources>
                    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </Style>
                    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                </TreeView>
```

I have seperate classes for Operations, Parameters and Joints that look like this:

Operations:

```
    public class Operation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Parameters> Parameters { get; set; }

    public Operation()
    {
        Parameters = new ObservableCollection<Parameters>();
    }
}
```

Parameters:

```
    public class Parameters
{
    public string par { get; set; }
    public double val { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Joints> Joints { get; set; }

    public Parameters()
    {
        Joints = new ObservableCollection<Joints>();
    }
}
```

Joints:

```
    public class Joints
{
    public string Par { get; set; }
    public double Val { get; set; }
}
```

My ShellViewModel which implements all these classes at looks like this:

```
public BindableCollection<Operation> _Operations = new BindableCollection<Operation>();


private bool _IsExpanded;
public bool IsExpanded
{
    get 
    { return _IsExpanded; }
    set 
    { 
        _IsExpanded = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsExpanded);
    }
}
private bool _IsSelected;
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return _IsSelected; }
    set 
    { 
        _IsSelected = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsSelected);
    }
}

public Operation _Operation = new Operation();
int moveId = 0;

public BindableCollection<Operation> Operations
{
    get { return _Operations; }
    set 
    { 
        _Operations = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Operations);
    }
}

public ShellViewModel()
{

var moveOperation = new Operation
    {
        Id = moveId,
        Name = $"Move{moveId}"
    };
    Joints jt1 = new Joints() { Par = "J0", Val = 2.34 };
    Joints jt2 = new Joints() { Par = "J1", Val = 0.34 };
    Joints jt3 = new Joints() { Par = "J2", Val = 4.34 };
    Parameters parm = new Parameters { par = "a", val = 2.13 };
    parm.Joints.Add(jt1);
    parm.Joints.Add(jt2);
    parm.Joints.Add(jt3);
    moveOperation.Parameters.Add(parm);
    _Operations.Add(moveOperation);
```

The expected outcome is something like this:

```
 - Move1
    -a 2.13
    -Joints
      -J0 2.34
      -J1 0.34
      -J2 4.34
 - Move2
    -a 'some value'
    -Joints
      -J0 'some value'
      -J1 'some value'
      -J2 'some value'
```

What am i missing? Why i cannot see more than only my root\parent\operation node? And i can not expand it.

Comment: Your ShellViewModel code is incomplete. I suspect you're missing where you add moveOperation to Operations. Also, you setup IsSelected and IsExpanded to properties that don't exist in you models anywhere. Also, your models don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: i use NotifyOfPropertyChange which is Caliburn Micro implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged. moveOperation, IsSelected and IsExpanded are also in my ViewModel, i just forgot to add them in the question (i did edit it though thank you)!

Comment: I have Recreated your problem, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Operation}" ItemsSource="{Binding Operation}">
```

Should be updated to

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Operation}" ItemsSource="{Binding Operations}">
```

This will bind the collection correctly to both the TopLevelNode, and the Templates that follows.

Here is a [Github Demo](https://github.com/juanvan/CaliburnTreeView)